# Android 4.1 invisible views on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, android-view, invisible, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've received several reports from users that large parts of UI in my application just went invisible on their Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.1 and they are still clickable. I'm not able to reproduce it on any Android 4.1 emulator.

So the question is, what did Google mess up this time? Is it a known bug?

Comment: Do you have `xhdpi` layouts? Not sure Nexus is, but its a theory.

Comment: Nope, it's just the default ones. Remember the views are still clickable, they're just not showing.

Comment: Try to get screenshots from the users. This will help focusing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this myself.  My problem was in using layerType="software" in some layouts.  Getting rid of that fixed it.